# How do I send the metric response from the JSON file to Cloud watch using AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the metric response in a JSON file and I want to send the metrics, "Size" and "fileCreatedAt" to Cloudwatch. In the future, I would like to get the metrics from the S3 bucket in AWS, but for now I wanted to write a Sample Code.

**This is the JSON File**

```
{
"nextToken": "sample-token",
  "files": [
    {
      "id": "xxxa",
      "fileCreatedAt": "2021",
      "size": 1234,
      "dataSourceId": "xx32"
    },
    {
      "id": "xxxb",
      "fileCreatedAt": "2022",
      "size": 3560,
      "dataSourceId": "xx33"
    },
    {
      "id": "xxxa",
      "fileCreatedAt": "2021",
      "size": 1234,
      "dataSourceId": "xx32"
    },
    {
      "id": "xxxb",
      "fileCreatedAt": "2022",
      "size": 3560,
      "dataSourceId": "xx33"
    }
]
}
```

**The boto3 Sample Code**

```
import json
import boto3
import botocore
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    cw_client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='myawsjsonbucket',Key='sample.json')
    metric_response = cw_client.put_metric_data( Namespace='JSON/AWS',
    MetricData=[
        {
            'MetricName': 'filesize',
            'Dimensions': [
                {
                    "Name": "size",
                    "Value": "some unique value"
                },
            ],
            'Value': size,
            'Timestamp': datetime.now()
        },
        {
            'MetricName': 'fileCreatedAt',
            'Dimensions': [
                {
                    "Name": "fileCreatedAt",
                    "Value": "some unique value"
                },
            ],
            'Value': fileCreatedAt,
            'Timestamp': datetime.now()
        },
    ]
        )
    print(response)
```

I tried to write the code to read the metrics from the metric response in the JSON file and transfer the metrics using boto3. Unfortunately, I got stuck with the boto code and I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: if you already have the `metric json` response why do you want to store in `cloudwatch`? just storing it into `S3` would make it accessible for future use. also how do you plan to provide the `json` response to `lambda` function ?

Comment: I want to store it in Cloudwatch so that I can send the data further to Grafana for monitoring. Unfortunately, I cannot directly send the metric response to Grafana, I have to first send it to cloudwatch and then to Grafana :) I am just trying with the JSON file for example, but in the future the response will directly come from input source and it would be connected to Cloudwatch and Grafana.

Comment: understood, can you tell where exactly are you facing challenge while using the `python` script ?

Comment: I am kind of stuck with the code after parsing my JSON file. I don't know how to read the metrics from the JSON file and send it to Cloudwatch. Should I read it as a list with for loop and insert boto3 client below the loop?

Comment: What metrics will you want to _retrieve_ from CloudWatch? If you know that, then you'll know what to send to CloudWatch Metrics. At its simplest, it would be a timestamp and a value. Is `fileCreatedAt` meant to be a timestamp? Or would you use "now" as the timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.put_metric_data), you can send the metric in a single request as well as in multiple request, whichever you feel efficient based on the input frequency

> You can publish either individual data points in the Value field, or arrays of values and the number of times each value occurred during the period by using the Values and Counts fields in the MetricDatum structure. Using the Values and Counts method enables you to publish up to 150 values per metric with one PutMetricData request, and supports retrieving percentile statistics on this data.
>
> Each PutMetricData request is limited to 1 MB in size for HTTP POST
> requests. You can send a payload compressed by gzip. Each request is
> also limited to no more than 1000 different metrics.

as per your snippet, you have to make the request like this

```
client.put_metric_data(
    Namespace='JSON/AWS', 
    MetricData=[
        {
            'MetricName': 'filesize', 
            'Dimensions': [
                {
                     "Name": "Size",
                     "Value": "some unique value"
                },
            ],
            'Value': size,
            'Timestamp': datetime.datetime.now()
        },
        {
            'MetricName': 'fileCreatedAt', 
            'Dimensions': [
                {
                     "Name": "fileCreatedAt",
                     "Value": "some unique value"
                },
            ],
            'Value': fileCreatedAt,
            'Timestamp': datetime.datetime.now()
        },
    ]
)
```

The `dimension` has 2 properties `name` and `value` which is used as an unique identifier of the dimension(I have kept `some unique value` so that it can be made for some grouping logic, otherwise for each filesize you will have multiple dimension). For passing the `value` of the dimension you have to pass it in the `Value` property.

An explanation of `dimension` is present in the docs

> A dimension is a name/value pair that is part of the identity of a metric. Because dimensions are part of the unique identifier for a metric, whenever you add a unique name/value pair to one of your metrics, you are creating a new variation of that metric. For example, many Amazon EC2 metrics publish InstanceId as a dimension name, and the actual instance ID as the value for that dimension.
>
> You can assign up to 30 dimensions to a metric.

Comment: Thank you very much Kaneki for the descriptive answer. You made my day. I have another quick question, if I want to send a bunch of data (more than 2) in JSON to aws cloudwatch, should I go for AWS-SDK ? Something like this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cloudwatch_example_cloudwatch_PutMetricData_DataSet_section.html ? How do I connect my JSON parse program with the boto3 code snippets you added? Is it through for loop?

Comment: by bunch of data, you mean more number of `metrics` or more `data points` under 1 `metric`?

Comment: More input  data points. I think I got it now. I will upload the JSON file to s3 bucket -> give permissions to lambda function and the data will be automatically sent to cloudwatch metrics ?

Comment: Sure, you can [refer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html#API_PutMetricData_Examples) this for more examples

Comment: Hey Kaneki, I have updated my code in the question. My code now takes data from S3 bucket and it also sends only one data point to Cloudwatch metrics. I want it do for all the data points in the JSON file, am I missing something here ? Should i do a for loop for the JSON file or something ? I went through the documentation, unfortunately i cannot find the solution for this :/ I also tried put_metrics_stream.

Comment: you have both options to send together or one by one. As I mentioned in the answer based on what you feel would be the most efficient way(depending on the flow of input source) you should choose. In the documentations you can see, if you want to pass one point then just pass in `Value` and if multiple then send an array in `Values`. Just give a try of the different options, and check in grafana side how it's behaving.